# betfair php api - error DSC-0021

Tags: curl, betfair

I have always DSC-0021 error on every method, except on getAccountFunds.

i have this request function

```
function send_request($api_method, $action, $params){

    if(!isset($_SESSION['session']) or empty($_SESSION['session'])){
        $_SESSION['session'] = login_non_interactive(APP_KEY);
    }

    $endpoint = 'https://api.betfair.com/exchange/account/json-rpc/v1';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-Application: ' . APP_KEY,
        'X-Authentication: ' . $_SESSION['session'],
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));

    $postData =
        '[{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "'.$api_method.'/v1.0/' . $action . '", "params" :' . $params . ', "id": 1}]';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

    if( ! $response = curl_exec($ch)){
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch)); 
    }

    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($http_status == 200) {
        return json_decode($response);
    } else {
        echo  'Error: ' . $response;
    }
}
```

- for balance(getAccountFunds) i got a valid and ok response

  $params = '{"wallet":"UK"}';

  $action = 'getAccountFunds';

  $api_method = 'AccountAPING';

  $balance = send_request($api_method, $action, $params);
- for other methods i got always DSC-0021

  $params = '{"filter":{}}';

  $action = 'listEventTypes';

  $api_method = 'SportsAPING';

  $res = send_request($api_method, $action, $params);
- sessionToken is valid and key too

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it not just the wrong endpoint?  Sports betting apis are on a different endpoint to the account apis.  See [here for accounts](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/x/III6) and [here for betting](https://api.developer.betfair.com/services/webapps/docs/x/g4E6).